# Performance overhead while using infer schema vs explicitly passing schema while loading CSV file data in spark dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am loading CSV data in spark dataframe with setting `inferSchema` option to `true`. Although the schema of my CSV file is always going to be same and I am aware of the exact schema.

Is it a good idea to manually provide the schema instead of inferring the schema? Does explicitly providing schema improves the performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's good. Schema Infter will cause that file will be read twice - once for Schema Infer, second for read into Dataset.

From Spark code for `DataFrameReader` - similar is in `DataStreamReader`:

> This function will go through the input once to determine the input
>   schema if `inferSchema`    is enabled. To avoid going through the
>   entire data once, disable `inferSchema` option or  specify the
>   schema explicitly using `schema`.

[Link to code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamReader.scala#L231)

However, it may be difficult to maintain schema for 100 Datasets with 200 columns each. You should also have in mind maintainability - so, typical answer will be - it depends :) For not-so-big schemas or not-so-difficult infer but with large files, I recommend using custom schema written in code

Comment: Can you please cite some source backing your first statement?

Comment: @vatsalmevada No, but you can simply observe it - with inferSchema there will be additional 3 jobs when calling csv(). With custom schema, the first job will be your job, for example count()

Comment: [inferSchema automatically infers column types. It requires one extra pass over the data](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features)

Comment: Thanks :)  @vatsalmevada I have also added comment from Spark code